# Generate color bar dynamically from Map

Tags: javascript, image, dictionary

I have many Maps showing mean of a specific variable and i'm interested in generating the color bar of those Maps dynamically with javascript .

Like take this map for example :https://content.lib.washington.edu/cmpweb/images/maps/rainfall_map.jpg

I want to be able to generate its colorbar with javascript any idea how can i do that ?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you expect. Do you want to show the percentage of each color?

Comment: @Tolokoban see this map http://12.000.scripts.mit.edu/mission2017/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Figure-1.jpg i have many Maps like that and in some of them there's for example only variation of blue and one red point hidden somewhere and that's not very interessting but affect the colorbar and you get a colorbar showing colors from blue to red but what will be interessting is to saturate the red point which i can already do with javascript ( process the image) and im 'interessted also in generating the color bar of that new map with the red point removed so the color bar will be more precise

Comment: If you already know how to process the image, you can compute an histogram of significant colors. Then you apply a threshold on it, keeping only colors greater than this threshold. At what point are you blocked? Are you doing this in the browser or in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following code will help you a bit.
Save the [map](http://12.000.scripts.mit.edu/mission2017/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Figure-1.jpg) image on your local drive and open it in the **Browse** button of this fiddler:

http://jsfiddle.net/kw4ycjbg/2/

First, I define the colors I want in my color bar:

```
var colors = [
    [235, 38, 42],
    [246, 146, 37],
    [255, 201, 10],
    [253, 244, 84],
    [187, 215, 96],
    [14, 175, 235],
    [32, 140, 205],
    [10, 73, 147]
];
```

Then, I count the number of pixels with a near color:

```
function nearestColor(R, G, B) {
    var bestDis = 5000;
    var bestIdx = -1;
    colors.forEach(function (color, idx) {
        var dis = (R - color[0])*(R - color[0])
            + (G - color[1])*(G - color[1])
            + (B - color[2])*(B - color[2]);
        if (dis < bestDis) {
            bestDis = dis;
            bestIdx = idx;
        }
    });
    return bestIdx;
}
```

I painted the color bar with a different size for each color. This represents my histogram. I think you can just keep the colors that appears more than a threshold.